# In Haskell, why isn't there a TypeClass for things that can act like lists?

Tags: list, haskell, typeclass

I'm reading [Learn You a Haskell](http://www.learnyouahaskell.com) and I'm wondering why so many things are acting like a list, and nothing in the Prelude is using the native facility of type classes to set this up:

> "The bytestring version of : is called cons It takes a byte and a bytestring and puts the byte at the beginning. It's lazy though, so it will make a new chunk even if the first chunk in the bytestring isn't full. That's why it's better to use the strict version of cons, cons' if you're going to be inserting a lot of bytes at the beginning of a bytestring."

Why isn't there a TypeClass *listable* or something that offers the `:` function to unify `Data.ByteString`, `Data.List`, `Data.ByteString.Lazy`, etc? Is there a reason for this, or is this just an element of legacy Haskell? Using `:` as an example is kind of an understatement, also from LYAH:

> Otherwise, the bytestring modules have a load of functions that are analogous to those in Data.List, including, but not limited to, head, tail, init, null, length, map, reverse, foldl, foldr, concat, takeWhile, filter, etc.

Comment: Can you explain how you imagine this working? It's clearly not possible to have a type class with both `ByteString` and `[]` as instances, since `[]` has kind `* -> *` and `ByteString` is just `*`.

Comment: @Travis Brown: You can do so with a trivially parameterized newtype wrapper. This has been reinvented several times, but an example is here http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/iteratee/0.2.1/doc/html/Data-Iteratee-WrappedByteString.html

Comment: If there's a library that does what you want, then why would it need to be included in the language proper?

Comment: @Robert, if I had them I would give you 10 more upvotes.

Comment: @Robert, @luqui, I don't understand your question, or your question doesn't make sense... Lets assume there wasn't a typeclass that provided `=`, and that the prelude provided a different function for each numeric type to test equality; furthermore, that each library followed the same convention. Would it not be a fair question then to ask why isn't  a type-class being used in the *language proper*. If you can answer this question, you're probably ready to answer mine.

Answer (score 31):

The [ListLike](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ListLike) package seems to provide what you're looking for.  I've never understood why it isn't more popular.

ListLike aside, one reason this isn't implemented in the Prelude is because it's not possible to do so well without invoking some language extensions (multi-param type classes and fundeps or associated types).  There are three sorts of containers to consider:

1. Containers that don't care about their elements at all (e.g. [])
2. Containers which are only implemented for specific elements (e.g. bytestrings)
3. Containers which are polymorphic over elements but require a context
   (e.g. Data.Vector.Storable, which will
   hold any type with a storable
   instance).

Here's a very basic ListLike-style class without using any extensions:

```
class Listable container where
  head :: container a -> a

instance Listable [] where
  head (x:xs) = x

instance Listable ByteString where --compiler error, wrong kind

instance Listable SV.Vector where
  head v = SV.head    --compiler error, can't deduce context (Storable a)
```

Here `container` has kind `*->*`.  This won't work for bytestrings because they don't allow an arbitrary type; they have kind `*`.  It also won't work for a Data.Vector.Storable vector, because the class doesn't include the context (the Storable constraint).

You can fix this problem by either changing your class definition to

```
class ListableMPTC container elem | container -> elem where
```

or

```
class ListableAT container where
  type Elem container :: *
```

Now `container` has kind `*`; it's a fully-applied type constructor.  That is, your instances look like

```
instance ListableMPTC [a] a where
```

but you're no longer Haskell98.

That's why even a simple Listable-type interface is non-trivial; it gets a bit harder when you have different collection semantics to account for (e.g. queues).  The other really big challenge is mutable-vs.-immutable data.  So far every attempt I've seen (except one) punts on that issue by creating a mutable interface and an immutable one.  The one interface I know which did unify the two was mind-bending, invoked a bunch of extensions, and had quite poor performance.

Addendum: bytestrings

Totally conjecture on my part, but I think we're stuck with bytestrings as a product of evolution.  That is, they were the first solution to low performance I/O operations, and it made sense to use `Ptr Word8`s for interfacing with IO system calls.  Operations on pointers require Storable, and most likely the necessary extensions (as described above) to make polymorphism work weren't available then.  Now it's difficult to overcome their momentum.  A similar container with polymorphism is certainly possible, the storablevector package implements this, but it's not anywhere near as popular.

Could bytestrings be polymorphic without any restrictions on the elements?  I think the closest Haskell has to this is the Array type.  This isn't nearly as good as a bytestring for low-level IO because data needs to be unpacked from the pointer into the array's internal format.  Also the data is boxed, which adds significant space overhead.  If you want unboxed storage (less space) and efficient interfacing with C, pointers are the way to go.  Once you have a Ptr, you need Storable, and then you need to include the element type in the type class, so then you're left with requiring extensions.

That being said, I think that with the appropriate extensions available this is essentially a solved problem for any single container implementation (modulo mutable/immutable APIs).  The harder part now is coming up with a sensible set of classes that are usable for many different types of structures (lists, arrays, queues, etc.) and is flexible enough to be useful.  I personally would expect this to be relatively straightforward, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I'm new to Haskell, so go lite on me: why does a ByteString have a kind of `*`. That seems rather random too -- why not make it polymorphic? I think I can understand the reasoning currently, but isn't assuming an 8 bit byte a totally needless assumption? Why not permit a `ByteString[Word7]` or something with a type synonym alias that makes a `ByteString` more like a `String`... With that said, I like this answer the most because it makes an attempt to explain why this isn't trivial. Would an update on Haskell language to standardize GHC pragmas make this trivial?

Comment: @Evan: edited my reply to address the questions on bytestrings.

Answer (score 19):

The main problem with such a class is that even if it existed it would only offer a superficial similarity.

The *asymptotics* of the same algorithm built using different structures would vary tremendously.

In the case of strict bytestrings building them up with cons is **terrible**, because you wind up copying the entire string every time you add another Char. This *O(1)* operation on a list turns it into an *O(n)* operation on a Bytestring.

This leads to *O(n^2)* behavior when you implement the first algorithm that might come to mind, map, whereas building up a list or Data.Sequence.Seq with cons is linear time and it can be implemented in *O(n)* for bytestrings or vectors as well with a little bit of thought.

It turns out the utility of such a class in light of this is more superficial than actual.

I'm not saying that a good design can't be found, but such a design would be difficult to use and to optimize for and likely a usable version of the design would not wind up being Haskell 98.

I've eked out portions of this design space in my keys package, which provides a lot of functions for indexing into containers, etc, but I've deliberately avoided providing a list-like API a.) because it has been done before to little success and b.) because of the asymptotic concerns above.

**tl;dr** You typically want to implement algorithms very differently when the asymptotics of the underlying operations change.

Comment: That is a really good point that I had not previously thought about. But after thinking about it I'm not sure I fully agree, there already exists many functions in Haskell base that have different asymptotes based on the value passed in. Hell even + has different asymptotes based on whether you pass in an Int or an Integer, and if you made a custom matrix like type that implemented + you could end up with an O(n) +. Also tons of other languages have functions with varying asymptotes. (Java ArrayList / LinkedList). I really think the utility is far from superficial. Imperfect perhaps.

Answer (score 14):

> that offers the : function to unify Data.ByteString, Data.List, Data.ByteString.Lazy, etc?

There have been attempts to come up with a good a) sequence interface, and b) containers interface, however, unifying data types of different kinds, with different type constraints, has generally made the results non-standard enough that it is hard to imagine putting them in the base library. Similarly for arrays, though the Vector package now has a fairly general interface (based on associated data types).

There are a couple of projects  to unify these various semi-related data types with a single interface, so I'm hopeful we'll see a result soon. Similarly for container types. The result won't be trivial though.

Comment: Is Data.Foldable an appropriate solution?

Comment: @phil: Data.Foldable and Data.Traversable are great, but neither offers anything close to a complete interface.

Comment: I'm less hopeful about progress on this.  I see two big flaws in most current efforts.  The first is that people want to re-use existing type classes in ways they aren't particularly suited IMHO (`Monoid` is a common example).  The second is that most attempts I've seen so far involve big, monolithic classes (such as `ListLike`), which rather hamstrings instance writers when their instance can't quite implement all the required methods.  I don't think a solution is impossible, but it's definitely non-trivial.

Comment: @JohnL Has this changed 13 years later?

Answer (score 0):

There are the two type classes called `Foldable` and `Traversable` which aim to abstract some common1 behaviours of lists and other sequential data structures. Not all data structures have instances of these though, and I don't know if they are transparent enough to the compiler such that it can still perform optimisation on them (does anybody know something about that?)

Source: [Foldable and Traversable](https://wiki.haskell.org/Fol/dable_and_Traversable)
See also this answer to 
[Why is Haskell missing “obvious” Typeclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25192678/854672)

Answer (score 0):

There actually is an `OverloadedLists` extension and an `IsList` class in `GHC.Exts` to go with it.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a lot of value to having a type class for list-like data in Haskell.  Why?  **Because of laziness.**  You can just write a function that converts your data to a list, and then use that list.  The list will only get constructed as its sublists and elements are demanded, and their memory will be eligible for collection as soon as no references remain to the prefixes.

There is value for a type class that provides a generic `toList` function—however, that already exists in [`Data.Foldable`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Foldable.html).

So basically, the solution is to implement `Data.Foldable` and use its `toList` function.

Comment: That only helps with consuming data. The question was, at very least, asking about generic construction functions as well. `Foldable` doesn't give you anything like that.

Comment: I don't think that converting, say, a `Vector` to a list and back again is a viable option when all you want is to basically use `(:)` instead of `cons` as a syntactical convenience.

Answer (score -2):

ByteString is not a generic type.

In other languages, there is something like `Sequence` for all list-like data structures.
I think this works, with correct extensions:

```
class Seq a b | a -> b where
  head :: a -> b
  isTail :: a -> Bool

# ([a]) is a sequence of a's
instance Seq [a] a where
  head (x:xs) = x
  isTail = (== [])

# ByteString is a sequence of chars
instance Seq ByteString Char
```

Or try this?

```
type BS a = ByteString
instance List BS
```