# Why can't I use String as a type class?

Tags: haskell

This is an absolute beginner Haskell question. Probably needs a couple of edits.

Given the following code:

```
import Data.Maybe
someFunction :: String b => Int -> Maybe b
someFunction x = Nothing
```

I get the error:

```
Main.hs@2:18-2:26`String' is applied to too many type arguments
In the type signature for `someFunction':
  someFunction :: String b => Int -> Maybe b
```

I'd like to understand exactly why I see this error.

The a Similar signature works for:

```
import Data.Maybe
somethingElse :: Num b => Int -> Maybe b
somethingElse x = Nothing
```

What's the difference between Num and String that causes this? (probably because String is not a type class?)

Can I create a shorthand for String in a similar fashion to Num? (probably yes?)

How can I find the correct type class to use if I'm in such a situation?

**UPDATE:**

To illustrate the reason I want to have a shorthand for the String type:

```
somethingElse ::  String -> String -> String -> String
somethingElse x s t  =  t ++ s ++ x
```

This compiles, but I'd prefer to write:

```
somethingElse :: ??? a => a -> a -> a -> a
somethingElse x s t  =  t ++ s ++ x
```

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `-XOverloadedStrings`? That makes string literals have type `IsString s => s`.

Comment: I could be Eduardo, but I'm a little more clueless than that. I'll look into it and get more clues. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I might miss something, but I think the problem is that `Num` is a parametric `class` (or typeclass) while String is a `type` ( or alias for the data type `[Char]`) that takes no type parameters.

Comment: You're right that `String` is not a type class, but why do you want a type class?

Comment: @raymonad: Perhaps so his code can work for arbitrary string implementations? (Just guessing.)

Comment: @raymonad I'm mostly just trying to wrap my head around why it wouldn't just work. I can imagine having a shorthand is convenient if there are many String parameters though. I'll try edit the sample to make that more clear.

Comment: @iwein That explains where you're coming from, but that's not what type classes are for. To get a shorter or more descriptive name, we use type synonyms, but `String` is already a synonym for `[Char]` and it's reasonably short. If you have so many `String` parameters that you feel the need to introduce a shorthand notation, you should probably do some refactoring instead.

Comment: @raymonad light is slowly starting to come on here. I understand that for some reason the Haskell language doesn't consider it to be possible to have arbitrary String implementations (by default). And you're totally right about the point of needing refactoring if I do something like that for real.

Comment: btw, I'm awed by the response times and tolerance for noob questions. It is **very** motivating to know that there is such a supportive community behind Haskell. Thanks for teaching!

Comment: There’s [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623612/in-haskell-why-isnt-there-a-typeclass-for-things-that-can-act-like-lists) on the lack of a container-like common typeclass, with several good answers. That being said, there *are* e.g. `Foldable` and `Traversable` (as well as their monomorphized versions) that capture certain aspects of a container, at least when it comes to reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original post asks for "short hand" of `String`. However, I thing what you have did for `Num` example is actually **abstraction** of functions. You have made your first `somethingElse` function works for other kind of numbers (doubles, complexes etc) as well!

In the same sense you can use `Monoid` type class for your second `somethingElse` function, as the following:

```
import Data.Monoid

somethingElse :: Monoid a => a -> a -> a -> a
somethingElse x s t = t <> s <> x
```

So you can say

```
somethingElse "World!" ", " "Hello"
```

and get

```
"Hello, World!"
```

**Explaination**

You were asking for a type class for `String`. There is no such thing like that in Haskell because `String` is just another name for `[Char]`.

Even `[]` in haskell is **NOT** a type class. Type classes in Haskell is a concept that helps you extract abstract behaviors of concrete data types. But `[]` is a concrete data type (although it have 1 type parameter).

According to your use, you are interesting in the ability of `[]` of concatenating. There is a type class that capture this kind of behavior. This type class is `Monoid`. Its `mappend` or `<>` operator does exactly the same as `++` for `[]` but it can work for other `Monoid` types as well. For example, when use with `Sum Int`, `<>` effectively sums up its parameters and gives you the total result.

So this is what you actually want: the `Monoid` type class does the right thing for `String`, and makes your last `somethingElse` function have the expected form of type signature.

But keep in mind: `Monoid` caputures only `++` operator of `List`, if you need something else, you will need other abstractions.

Comment: Nice, very educational solution.

Answer (score 5):

### Updated answer:

After reading your comment to @YellPika 's answer, scratch what I previously said. If you want to define a shorter type synonym for `String`, all you have to do is

```
-- Not that this serves any useful purpose.
type Str = String
```

Then you can use the synonym in type annotations:

```
someFunction :: Int -> Maybe Str
someFunction x = Nothing
```

But, really, this is a bad idea. Everyone knows that `String` stands for `[Char]`, because it is in the standard library. Only you would know that your synonym `Str` stands for `String`. If you are concerned with long type annotations, you can use Haskell's type inference.

`Num` is a *type class*, not a type. A [type class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class) defines a collection of methods that be provided for multiple types [in an ad-hoc fashion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism). The closest analog in a mainstream language would be the notion of [concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept) in C++'s standard library and the original STL. (However, type classes are native constructs of the Haskell language, while C++/STL concepts only exist in the heads of C++ programmers.)

---

### What I previously said:

(Left here just for reference)

You might be looking for the `-XOverloadedStrings` extension. That makes string literals have type `IsString s => s`.

Here is an example from a ghci session:

```
> :set -XOverloadedStrings
> import Data.String
> import Data.ByteString
> import Data.Text
> :t "a"
"a" :: IsString a => a
> :i IsString
class IsString a where
  fromString :: String -> a
    -- Defined in `Data.String'
instance IsString ByteString
  -- Defined in `Data.ByteString.Internal'
instance IsString Text -- Defined in `Data.Text'
instance IsString [Char] -- Defined in `Data.String'
```

In a Haskell source file (*.hs), you can use this extension by adding at the top:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module What.Ever where

-- ...
```

**Note:** All of this assumes you are using GHC. I have not tried other Haskell implementations.

Comment: This worked for me. I still don't understand why I would need special compiler options and an additional import for it. Still scratching my head.

Comment: @iwein: This just enables you to use arbitrary string implementations. You do not need any of this if you want string literals to stand for linked lists of `Char`s.

Comment: "The closest analog in a mainstream language" - Haskell isn't mainstream!?

Comment: @YellPika: As much as I love Haskell, no, Haskell is not mainstream yet.

Comment: @EduardoLeón what you previously said was actually more interesting than the answer to my original question. Do you know the reason why there is no type class for String by default? String being final in Java has always annoyed me.

Comment: @iwein: I totally agree that `String` (or perhaps `Str`) should be a type class, without having to use a GHC extension.

Comment: @iwein "String being final... always annoyed me" Haskell might be a bit irritating then :) Everything here is immutable. This extension just gives strings the type `IsString a => a` much like numeric literals have the type `Num a => a`

Comment: @jozefg: In Java, a class being `final` means it cannot be inherited. `java.lang.String` also happens to be immutable, but that is independent of it being `final`. (I can see how this is confusing, though, because variables being `final` means they are immutable.)

Comment: @jozefg I love immutability, and I love of the freedom to inherit types as I see fit. I'm sure Haskell will be more tolerable than Java :)

Comment: @iwein: Haskell does not have a notion of inheritance for types. The "type space" is flat. Type classes can be hierarchically related, though.

Answer (score 5):

The error is somewhat misleading. String (defined as `type String = [Char]`) has no type parameters, but you're giving it one (`String b`).

However, only type classes can be specified in constraints (i.e. before the `=>`), so what you're attempting would fail to compiler regardless of how many arguments you gave `String`.

What (I think) you want to do is simply `someFunction :: Int -> Maybe String`.

---

Well, if you want a shorthand, then I suppose you can just do this:

```
type S = String

someFunction :: Int -> Maybe S
```

Although I think that obfuscates the code a bit.

As a side note: Type classes are *not* for creating locally defined shorthands for a type.

---

### Addition:

I just remembered that you can emulate shorthands using type equality constraints.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-} -- Or GADTs

somethingElse :: s ~ String => s -> s -> s -> s
somethingElse x y z = x ++ y ++ z
```

By using type equalities, the "synonym" is now locally defined, and thus less confusing to read than defining `type SomeOtherNameForStringThatIsShorterThan'String' = String`.

But I would still recommend just writing out the full type.

Comment: Your solution works, and it solves part of my puzzle too. However, having a shorthand for String in case I need many string parameters in my function seems to make sense… to me at least.

Comment: @iwein: Oooooooooooooooh. That comment is very revealing. Then my answer does not tackle the fundamental issue at hand.

Comment: @EduardoLeón it mostly reveals my ignorance I'm sure :)