# Why is Haskell missing "obvious" Typeclasses

Tags: haskell, typeclass, abstraction, standard-library

**Consider the Object-Oriented Languages:**

Most people coming from an object-oriented programming background, are familiar with the common and intuitive interfaces in various languages that capture the essence of Java's [**`Collection`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) & [**`List`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interfaces. **`Collection`** refers to a  collection of objects which doesn't necessarily have an natural ordering/indexing. A **`List`** is a collection which has a natural ordering/indexing. These interfaces abstract many library data-structures in Java, as do their equivalent interfaces in other languages, and an intimate understanding of these interfaces are required to work effectively with most library data-structures.

**Transition to Haskell:**

Haskell has a type-class system which acts on types analogously to interfaces on objects. Haskell seems to have a [well designed type-class hierarchy](http://www.haskell.org/wikiupload/d/df/Typeclassopedia-diagram.png) with regard to Functors, Applicative, Monads, etc. when the type regard functionality. They obviously want [correct and well-abstracted type-classes](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal). Yet when you look at many Haskell's containers ([**`List`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html),[**`Map`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.2.0.1/docs/Data-Map.html),[**`Sequence`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html),[**`Set`**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers-0.5.5.1/Data-Set.html),[**`Vector`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.9.1/docs/Data-Vector.html)) they almost all have very similar (or identical) functions, yet aren't abstracted through type-classes.

**Some Examples:**

- `null` for testing "emptyness"
- `length`**/**`size` for element count
- `elem`**/**`member` for set inclusion
- `empty` *and/or* `singleton` for default construction
- `union` for set union
- `(\\)`**/**`diff` for set difference
- `(!)`**/**`(!!)` for unsafe indexing (partial function)
- `(!?)`**/**`lookup` for safe indexing (total function)

If I want to use any of the functions above, but I have imported two or more containers I have to start hiding functions from the imported modules, or explicitly import only the necessary functions from the modules, or qualifying the imported modules. But since all the functions provide the same logical functionality, it just seems like a hassle. If the functions were defined from type-classes, and not separately in each module, the compiler's type inference mechanics could resolve this. It would also make switching underlying containers simple as long as they shared the type-classes (ie: lets just use a `Sequence` instead of `List` for better random access efficiency).

Why doesn't Haskell have a **`Collection`** and/or **`Indexable`** type-class(es) to unify & generalize some of these functions?

Comment: [Collection](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/EdisonAPI), [Indexable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/keys)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8484117/257418

Comment: @DanielWagner Sure, but none of the library containers are instances of these type-classes. Isn’t terribly usable out-of-the-box...

Comment: To comment briefly on my close vote: since there evidently *are* libraries providing the typeclass in question, it seems to me the most charitable way to interpret this question might be "Why aren't people using these typeclasses?". I believe it's difficult to answer this question in an objective, useful way.

Comment: Some food for the mind: How would a library handle additional constraints? Compare `isMember :: Ord k => k -> Set k -> Bool` vs `isMember :: a -> [a] -> Bool`. Or indexing: `at :: Int -> [a] -> Maybe a` vs `at :: Unbox a => Int -> Vector a -> Maybe a` (for unboxed vectors). Other than that, I concur with Daniel, it's hard to answer in an objective way. If you can create your specific version of `Collection`, go for it, and add it to hackage.

Comment: @awashburn: I wouldn't recommend `Collection`, but `Indexable` works out-of-the-box allright and has all the instances you asked for. And of course it's much more sophisticated than anything you could possibly write in Java...

Comment: @Zeta `elem :: (Eq a) => a -> Collection a -> Bool` doesn't seem that impossible to abstract by making `Map` & `List` instances of the fictional `Collection` type-class.

Comment: @awashburn: You probalby mean `elem :: (Eq a, Collection c) => a -> c a -> Bool`. However, in this case you can't use the logarithmic `member` search of `Map` and `Set`, since both need `Ord a` to find an element efficiently. That way you're loosing a great part of the performance (O(log n) -> O(n)).

Comment: @awashburn: { ... duplicate of Zeta's comment, removed ... } That said, an efficient generic `elem` would actually be possible with `ConstraintKinds`.

Comment: Minor note: you can test for emptiness using a `Monoid` and `Eq` constraint: `null :: (Monoid m, Eq m) => m -> Bool ; null x = x == mempty`

Comment: Sequence has not better random access; Sequence from Data.Sequence is a DeQue (a double ended queue) with constant access from both heads but accessing in between has O(log(min(i,n-i))) as [documented](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Sequence.html#v:index)

Comment: @GabrielRiba **`O(log(min(i,n-i))`** is better then **`O(n)`**, right?

Comment: Indeed, finger trees are nice like that; of course, you pay for that flexibility with larger constant factors. So if you *only* need random access, or *only* need access at one/both ends, you should use a different structure.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I like the [**`Indexable`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/keys) type-class you guys pointed out. It's just sad that it is built on top of the containers in another module, rather then with the containers in their respective modules. The type-class consequently has poor viability for Haskell programmers, making it harder to adopt it as a standardization...

Comment: Take a look at [IsSequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-0.6.1/docs/Data-Sequences.html) and other [containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-0.6.1/docs/Data-Containers.html) in [mono-traversable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Partly, the reason is that monads and arrows are new, innovative features of Haskell, while collections are relatively more mundane.  Haskell has a long history as a research language; interesting research questions (designing monad instances & defining generic operations for monads) get more development effort than "industrial-strength" polishing (defining container APIs).

Partly, the reason is that those types come from three different packages (base, containers, and vector), with three separate histories and designers.  That makes it harder for their designers to coordinate on providing instances of any single type class.

Partly, the reason is that defining a single type class to cover all five of the containers you mentioned is really hard.  List, Sequence, and Vector are relatively similar, but Map and Set have completely different constraints.  For List, Sequence, and Vector, you want a simple constructor class, but for Set that won't work, since Set requires an Ord instance on the element type.  Even worse, Map can support most of your methods, but its singleton function needs two parameters where the rest need only one.

Comment: Interesting, I had never thought of Haskell's academic skew vs industry usage as an explanation...

Comment: I believe these issues of a universal typeclass could be solved by `ConstraintKinds` and and `TypeFamilies`

Comment: After much deliberation, I felt your answer best addressed the spirit of my question.

Answer (score 42):

As other answers have pointed out, Haskell tends to use different vocabulary. However, I don't think they've explained the *reason* for the difference very well.

In a language like Java, functions are not "first class citizens"; it's true that anonymous functions are available in the latest versions, but this style of interface (Collection, Indexable, Interable, etc.) were designed before that.

This makes it tedious to pass our code around, so we prefer *other people's data* to be passed to *our code*. For example:

- Data implementing Java's `Iterable` lets *us* write `for (Foo x : anIterable) { ... }`
- Data implementing PHP's `ArrayAccess` lets *us* write `anArrayAccess[anIndex]`

This style can also be seen in OO languages which implement generators, since that's another way for *us* to write `for yieldedElement in aGenerator: ...`.

Haskell takes a different approach with its typeclasses: we prefer *our code* to be passed to *other people's data*. Some (simplified) examples:

- `Functor`s accept our code and apply it to any elements they 'contain'
- `Monad`s accept our code and apply it in some kind of 'sequence'
- `Foldable`s accept our code and use it to 'reduce' their contents

Java only needs `Iterable` since *we* have to call our code in *our* `for` loop, so we can make sure it's called correctly. Haskell requires more specific typeclasses since *someone else's code* will be calling ours, so we need to specify *how* it should be called; is it a `map`, a `fold`, an `unfold`, etc.?

Thankfully, the type system helps us choose the right method ;)

Comment: Cool answer - I believe it gives the most fundamental reason for the lack of "data interface" typeclass. But it also invites us to look data access problems the "other way around".

Answer (score 37):

The [`lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package provides some of this.

- **Testing for emptiness, creating empty containers** These are both provided by the `AsEmpty` typeclass from [`Control.Lens.Empty`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.3.3/docs/Control-Lens-Empty.html).
- **Accessing elements by key/index**. The `At` and `Ixed` typeclasses from [`Control.Lens.At`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.3.3/docs/Control-Lens-At.html).
- **Checking for membership in set-like containers**. The `Contains` typeclass from [`Control.Lens.At`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.3.3/docs/Control-Lens-At.html).
- **Appending and deleting elements to sequence-like containers**. The `Cons` and `Snoc` typeclasses from [`Control.Lens.Cons`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.3.3/docs/Control-Lens-Cons.html).

Also, the `pure` method of the `Applicative` typeclass can often be used to create "singleton" containers. For things that are not functors/applicatives in Haskell, like `Set`, perhaps `point` from [`Data.Pointed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointed-4.1/docs/Data-Pointed.html) could be used.

Comment: I really think that many of lens's typeclasses are solutions to Haskell's module problems, including "programming against interfaces" like in this example.

Answer (score 28):

Haskell has some type classes for working with collections in the base package: [Functor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#t:Functor), [Foldable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Foldable.html#t:Foldable) and [Traversable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Traversable.html#t:Traversable) can be useful for working with collections, and the [Monoid](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Monoid.html), [Applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative) and/or [Alternative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative) typeclasses can be useful for constructing collections.

Together, these classes cover most of the operations mentioned in the question, but maybe less efficient than a more container-specific function (though many of these are class methods, whose default definitions can be overriden if necessary).

> `null` for testing "emptyness"

Foldable supports `null` since *base* 4.8 (`any (const True)` is an alternative for earlier versions).

> length/size for element count:

Foldable supports `length` since *base* 4.8 (`getSum . foldMap (const 1)` is an alternative for earlier versions).

> elem/member for set inclusion

Foldable supports `elem`, `notElem` and `member`.

> empty and/or singleton for default construction

For empty, there is `mempty` from Monoid and `empty` from Alternative.
For singleton, there is `pure` from Applicative.

> union for set union

There is `mappend` from Monoid and `<|>` from Alternative. They don't necessarily implement set union, but they implement some form of union that works well together with empty and usually also with singleton and find.

> (\)/diff for set difference

This one is not supported, unfortunately.

> (!)/(!!) for unsafe indexing (partial function)

You could use `fromJust` together with a function for safe indexing.

> (!?)/lookup for safe indexing (total function)

There is `find` from Foldable.

Comment: Does `elem` from `Foldable` actually use the internal structure of the container to speed up the check? If not, using it instead of container-specific functions could hurt performance.

Comment: Good point, it looks like `elem` just scans through the container.

Comment: I feel that, while functional, these suggestions don't correctly capture the intended abstractions. The *intention* in many of your examples are not readily deductible... The info from  [**`Foldable`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Foldable.html) is interesting though!

Comment: You can think of `Foldable` as a fancy way of saying there's a function `Foldable f => f a -> [a]`---so then all instantiators inherit a lot of functionality from `List`.

Comment: a minor improvement on your `length`: `getSum . foldMap (const 1)`

Comment: With more recent versions of *base* (>= 4.8), `null` and `length` are methods of `Foldable`.

Answer (score 13):

Such typeclasses exist in standard Haskell, but they don't have the same name as their equivalent OO counterparts. The `Collection` typeclass, for example, is called `Foldable` in Haskell. You can use it to test if a structure is empty (`foldr (const False) True x`) or to count the number of elements (`foldMap (const 1) x`), or to test for set membership (`foldr (\e' present -> (e==e') || present) False x` for some `e`).

For operations like element lookup, you have the `Array` typeclass which might work for sequential data. For more flexibility, you can write your own `Indexable` class, like this for example (beware of lenses) :

```
class Indexable m k a where
  at :: k -> Lens' m (Maybe a)
```

The null element and set union belong to the `Monoid` typeclass (where `mappend == union`). In this light, set difference could also be implemented in its own typeclass `Differentiable` (which I'm sure already exists in dozens of Haskell libraries) and we would have total compatibility with imperative languages.

Haskell, by virtue of being designed by mathematicians and the like, doesn't employ the same vocabulary as most other languages, but rest assured, it doesn't mean that it's not a practical language in addition to being an awesome one :-)

Answer (score 12):

Laws.  A good typeclass has laws.  A great typeclass has enough parametricity so that it's laws are "theorems for free".  A typeclass without laws is just ad-hoc name overloading.

Also, check out [classy-prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/classy-prelude-0.9.3/docs/ClassyPrelude.html) and [Edison-API](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/EdisonAPI).

Answer (score 9):

You have typeclasses for different collection aspects:

1. composition: Monoid (module Data.Monoid)
2. sequential control: Applicative, Monad  (modules Control.Applicative, Control.Monad)
3. sequential composition: Alternative, MonadPlus (modules Control.Applicative, Control.Monad)
4. non-sequential mapping and reduction: Functor (mod. Data.Functor), Foldable (mod. Data.Foldable)
5. sequential mapping and reduction: Traversable (module Data.Traversable)
6. serialisation: Binary (mod. Data.Binary)
7. comparison: Eq, Ord (mod. Data.Eq, Data.Ord)
8. textualisation: Show, Read
9. deep evaluation (to Normal Form): NFData (mod. Control.DeepSeq)
10. generic datatype traversability: Data (mod. Data.Data)

Except that monomorphic collections (ByteString, IntSet, Text) cannot implement Functor and Foldable (they require type arity == 1 (Kind: * -> *))

Also [neither (Set a) implements Functor](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2090x3/ask_rhaskell_why_is_there_no_functor_instance_for/).

The package [mono-traversable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable) redefines some classes without the monomorphic types exclusion.

*Update*. There is an attempt to put most functions in typeclasses with the packages [mono-traversable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable) and [classy-prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/classy-prelude).

[library ref](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/), [platform](http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/)