# Where is the Set type class?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

In Haskell [`Data.Set`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Set.html) implements a concrete set type. Normal `[]` lists also implement all operations of a set (in [`Data.List`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html)). But there seems to be no predefined `Set` typeclass that they both implement. You can implement one yourself:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, FunctionalDependencies #-}

module Set where

import qualified Data.List as ConcreteList
import qualified Data.Set as ConcreteSet

class Set set a | set -> a where
  empty :: set
  singleton :: a -> set
  insert :: a -> set -> set
  delete :: a -> set -> set
  union :: set -> set -> set
  intersection :: set -> set -> set
  member :: a -> set -> Bool
  filter :: (a -> Bool) -> set -> set

instance (Ord a) => Set (ConcreteSet.Set a) a where
  empty = ConcreteSet.empty
  singleton = ConcreteSet.singleton
  insert = ConcreteSet.insert
  delete = ConcreteSet.delete
  union = ConcreteSet.union
  intersection = ConcreteSet.intersection
  member = ConcreteSet.member
  filter = ConcreteSet.filter

instance (Eq a) => Set [a] a where
  empty = []
  singleton e = [e]
  insert = (:)
  delete = ConcreteList.delete
  union = ConcreteList.union
  intersection = ConcreteList.intersect
  member = ConcreteList.elem
  filter = ConcreteList.filter
```

but it seems that this would already have been done if this was the way to go. So my question is: Where is the `Set` typeclass or what alternative solution has the Haskell community come up with?

My question is admittedly quite similar to [Why is Haskell missing “obvious” Typeclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191659/why-is-haskell-missing-obvious-typeclasses), but by being more concrete (focusing on a specific example with sample implementation), I'm hoping to get some more concrete answers as well.

Comment: but those two behave differently: `delete 1 (insert 1 (insert 1 empty))` will be empty in one but not in the other... (which you can check with `member` if you argue that there is no equality implied)

Comment: @Carsten, you just found a bug in my implementation.

Comment: ;) - it's just that I think of  a very specific entity if I say `Set` (that's why I would call it collection or something

Comment: @Carsten Seems easy enough to fix by having `delete` for `List` delete *all* matching items, not just the first one.

Comment: You might also be interested in the answers to [Why is Haskell missing "obvious" Typeclasses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191659/why-is-haskell-missing-obvious-typeclasses)

Answer (score 7):

For whatever reason, Haskell tends not to do the whole thing of having deep hierarchies of type classes for representing all possible sorts of containers.

Generally, different sorts of containers have performance properties for different operations. Typically you know what operations are important to you, and you choose the most suitable container and use that explicitly. There's not much requirement to be able to write really generic code that operates over every possible kind of container.

Note that there are *some* type classes for dealing with containers already — they're just not the ones you might be expecting. For example:

- `Functor` allows you to apply a function to every element of a container — *any* container — and collect the results into a new container of the same type.
- `Applicative` and/or `Monad` allow you to apply a function to every element and produce more than one element as result. (It may not be obvious, but you can use this to perform "filtering" and even "deletion", although it's probably not efficient.)
- `Monoid` provides your `empty` and `union` methods (but named `mempty` and `mappend`).
- `Alternative`, `Foldable` and `Traversable` let you do further interesting magic.

Comment: I reckon a major reason Haskell doesn't have so many superclasses is that, if you really need such a class, you can _at any point later_ define it yourself and make the suitable instances for any types you want. The type doesn't need to know anything about classes you put it in, unlike with Java where the types themselves are classes and need to specify their superclasses themselves.

Comment: Sometimes the needs of your program might change or perhaps aren't so clearcut to begin with, without testing which Set implementation has the best performance in your specific program.

Answer (score 6):

I'll annotate the class a bit:

```
-- The functional dependency here ties in to the issues with 
-- restricted type class instances, for which there is no one
-- globally adopted solution.
class Set set a | set -> a where
  -- This is a `Monoid`- or `Alternative`-like constant
  empty :: set

  -- This is an `Applicative`-like operation
  singleton :: a -> set

  -- If you have `singleton` and `union` you have `insert`.
  -- Which means that `insert` might fall out of the 
  -- `Alternative` class.
  insert :: a -> set -> set

  -- This looks like a variant of `filter` below.
  delete :: a -> set -> set

  -- These two are `Semigroup` operations
  union :: set -> set -> set
  intersection :: set -> set -> set

  -- Can't think of anything for this one.
  member :: a -> set -> Bool

  -- This is very `Monad`-like operation.  You can write this
  -- in terms of a bind/`unionMap` operation + your `singleton`
  -- and `empty`.
  filter :: (a -> Bool) -> set -> set
```

So basically, the community prefers a lot of small classes that are more reusable than this `Set` class would be.

Here's another point that might be useful.  You seem to be mentally tying classes to *types*, as a mental classification of types that are similar because they "represent sets."  But the Haskell community more often ties classes to **operations**.  You can see this in the annotation above, I hope—most of the operations that you propose remind me of some already existing class.  The black mark is the fact that most of those classes won't work with a type like `Set` that has an element type constraint...

Comment: I think your answer is the closest to the answer I'm looking for, but I'm still wondering how specifically you would choose to use this insight in the best possible way (in your opinion), to implement enough polymorphic operations that you can easily switch to a different implementation of a set, simply by changing the type of a function.

Answer (score 5):

You can try [`Data.Containers` from `mono-traversable`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-4.1/mono-traversable-0.10.0.1/Data-Containers.html)

Haskell code in general tends to have less of a leaning towards generalizing data types like this than, say, Java, which is why these abstractions aren't in [`containers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers) or [`unordered-containers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers).

Comment: That code comes with a: Warning: This module should be considered highly experimental.

Comment: Still somewhat true, but it hasn't changed in a significant way in over a year I believe.