# Is there a standard immutable "Map" (e.g. Data.Map, Data.HashMap) typeclass in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

It seems that the idea of a dictionary is one that gives rise to many different implementations, understandably. Since this is Haskell, I'll focus on immutable maps/hashes/dicts. I'd like to be able to use a typeclass for a little library I'm working on and allow users to choose their Hash/Map/Dict implementation.

If there isn't a standard typeclass, it seems that providing a typeclass via hackage might be useful, and failing that, one could (as a library/API provider) still find benefit from using the hackage package or one's own typeclass to allow users to choose a given implementation for a Map.

Assuming I haven't missed a typeclass for Dicts, is there anything in particular about immutable dictionaries that would not go well with typeclasses in Haskell?

**Update**

The more general question [Why is Haskell missing "obvious" Typeclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191659) provides a lot of useful insight that goes a long way towards answering this question, but doesn't offer practical solutions to this particular case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Haskell missing "obvious" Typeclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191659/why-is-haskell-missing-obvious-typeclasses)

Comment: This might be a better use for backpack than typeclasses.

Comment: Use [`At`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.3.3/docs/Control-Lens-At.html).

Answer (score 2):

There're some unsolvable problems with having typeclass for the `Map`-like data structures. Fortunately, Backpack helps. You can see the interface for `Map` via Backpack here:

- https://github.com/kowainik/containers-backpack

I've implemented this solution and a blog post about such interface:

- https://kowainik.github.io/posts/2018-08-19-picnic-put-containers-into-a-backpack

Comment: I had no idea that module Signatures existed, I can see this being very useful (especially for people wanting to avoid more "advanced" FP or Category Theory

Comment: One of the motivation behind Backpack is to keep simple Haskell. Having typeclass for `Map` most likely will involve advance features like `TypeFamilies`, so Backpack really shines here!

Comment: Sorry if I missed something obvious as I'm rather new to Haskell development, but I can't seem to find it on hackage. Is there a suggested way to use the project code externally? I saw https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/4206 so assume you may be waiting on that to publish to hackage.

Comment: Hmmm, I now see that backpacks are more than a conceptual idea and require using next.hackage (currently), but I don't see the packages there either.

Comment: @bbarker It's not on Hackage because maintaining it on Hackage requires to upload 20 packages. I would like to wait for _multiple public libraries_ support to be implemented first (it's almost done and will be merged to `cabal` in nearest days). Meanwhile you can depend on GitHub repository, `cabal` allows to specify dependency on GitHub directly.