# Minimal interface over Data.List and Data.Sequence in Haskell for prependable lists

Tags: haskell

I find that I am writing duplicate functions to handle Data.List and Data.Sequence, and in an attempt to generalize over them, I wrote:

```
import qualified Data.Sequence as Seq

class PrependableList pl where
  empty :: pl a
  first ::  pl a -> a
  prepend :: a -> pl a -> pl a
  len :: pl a -> Int

instance PrependableList [a] where
  empty = []
  first = head
  prepend = (:)
  len = length

instance PrependableList (Seq.Seq a) where
  empty = Seq.empty
  first seq = Seq.index seq 0
  prepend = (Seq.<|)
  len = Seq.length
```

The implementation above does not compile, indicating a kind mismatch:

```
Kind mis-match
The first argument of `PrependableList' should have kind `* -> *',
but `[a]' has kind `*'
In the instance declaration for `PrependableList [a]'

Kind mis-match
The first argument of `PrependableList' should have kind `* -> *',
but `Seq.Seq a' has kind `*'
In the instance declaration for `PrependableList (Seq.Seq a)'
```

From what I have seen in other entries (e.g. [In Haskell, why isn't there a TypeClass for things that can act like lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623612/in-haskell-why-isnt-there-a-typeclass-for-things-that-can-act-like-lists)), it might not be possible to generalize completely over multiple list-like data structures.

But could the above 4 functions be generalized at least for Data.List and Data.Sequence?

Comment: Just change `[a]` to `[]`.

Comment: As the error message points out, `PrependableList` expects a unary type constructor (`* -> *`), not a nullary one (`*`). Therefore, you should write `instance PrependableList []` and instance `PrependableList Seq.Seq`. Also, your code snippet won't compile unless you use the qualified name of the `<|` operator, i.e. `Seq.<|`.

Comment: Thanks @MathematicalOrchid, indeed that overcomes the compilation error. The next issue is then how to use PrependableList in a type definition of a function. When I add "PrependableList a", the compiler points out another kind mismatch:
"Kind mis-match
    The first argument of `PrependableList' should have kind `* -> *',
    but `a' has kind `*'"   (Can't make asterisks show properly)

Comment: Thanks @Jubobs -- fixed the Seq.<| issue.

Comment: @AlbertCardona You want something like `PrependableList pl => pl a`.

Comment: Thank you @MathematicalOrchid that was the last conceptual leap to go through.

Comment: Incidentally - https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13/docs/Control-Lens-Cons.html - but maybe that won't suit you.

Answer (score 3):

I know you've already answered this for yourself, but I wanted to point out Haskell has been evolving in recent years to try to encapsulate these ideas much more broadly, and your class is already a combination of two other existing classes:

```hs
import Control.Monad (MonadPlus, mzero, mplus);
import Data.Foldable (Foldable, length, toList);
import Data.Sequence (Seq)
import qualified Data.Sequence as S

-- same as your PrependableList
class Prependable p where
    empty :: p a
    first ::  p a -> a
    prepend :: a -> p a -> p a
    len :: p a -> Int

-- generic newtype wrapper
newtype WrapP p x = WrapP { unwrapP :: p x } deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

-- any foldable monadplus is prependable.
instance (MonadPlus m, Foldable m) => Prependable (WrapP m) where
    empty = WrapP mzero
    prepend = (WrapP .) . (. unwrapP) . mplus . return
    first = head . toList . unwrapP
    len = length . unwrapP 

-- specific cases
type SeqP x = WrapP Seq x
type ListP x = WrapP [] x
```

Furthermore since `WrapP` is a `newtype` you can usually replace `WrapP` and `unwrapP` with `id` as long as you also adjust the type signature; in particular we can write your four functions directly as:

```hs
empty   :: (Foldable m, MonadPlus m) => m x
empty = mzero
first   :: (Foldable m, MonadPlus m) => m x -> x
first = head . toList
prepend :: (Foldable m, MonadPlus m) => x -> m x -> m x
prepend = mplus . return
len     :: (Foldable m, MonadPlus m) => m x -> Int
len = length
```

and these now natively will work on both lists and Data.Sequence. (You may need a newer-ish version of GHC if `Prelude.length` is not the same as `Data.Foldable.length`, or else you have to import the Prelude  hiding `length` which you then explicitly import from Data.Foldable.

As `Data.Sequence` already defines both `MonadPlus` and `Foldable` for `Seq`, you're good to go in 8 lines of code with no new classes or instance declarations; moreover two of them are direct substitutions (`len` for `length`, `empty` for `mzero`), saving 4 more lines of code if you simply use the versions that were already defined for you.

(As a slight detour, `first` is also `extract` from `Control.Comonad`, with a (non-empty!) list's `extract` being `head` and its `duplicate` being `takeWhile (not . null) . tails` (using `Data.List.tails` but neglecting the last element `[]`). I don't think you can define `len` based purely on a `Comonad` infrastructure though; for that you would really need a `Foldable` type. A non-empty list can be put in a manifestly comonad form by writing it as `newtype NEList = NEList x (Maybe (NEList x))`, where we can then replace `NEList` with `Cofree Maybe` to see that it's a comonad.)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to you all, this is the correct code with a minimal example of usage:

```
    import qualified Data.Sequence as Seq

    class PrependableList pl where
        empty :: pl a
        first ::  pl a -> a
        prepend :: a -> pl a -> pl a
        len :: pl a -> Int

    instance PrependableList [] where
        empty = []
        first = head
        prepend = (:)
        len = length

    instance PrependableList Seq.Seq where
        empty = Seq.empty
        first seq = Seq.index seq 0
        prepend = (Seq.<|)
        len = Seq.length

    -- Example usage
    prependAll :: (PrependableList pl) => pl a -> [a] -> pl a
    prependAll plist xs = foldr prepend plist xs

    main = do
        print $ prependAll Seq.empty [1..5]
        print $ prependAll [] [1..5]
```

Which prints:

```
$ ./pl 
fromList [1,2,3,4,5]
[1,2,3,4,5]
```